# Updates stepping on nvidia drivers on ubuntu

Tags: nvidia

How can I update Ubuntu without needing to re-install the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible. In general packages built for one release don't work well on another. That is especially true for packages that depend on a particular kernel branch and the accompanying user land tools. What do you even want to achieve that makes you want to avoid an upgrade of the Nvidia driver package(s)?